# HighCharts Adding a Back Button when data is set through point.events.click

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Is there a way to set a back button when the data is set from point.events.click , it seems that setting it in

```
Highcharts.setOptions({
    lang: {
        drillUpText: 'Back'
    }
});
```

does not work when it is set up in point.events.click, I've tried a few options within events and most I can do is setup an alert.

http://jsfiddle.net/efiallo/bh6e4Lyq/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drillup button works only when the Highcharts **drilldown module** is imported and used. You implemented your own drilldown mechanism so the drillup button needs to be taken care of manually.

I aggregated all chart's defaults restoring operations in the `restore` function:

```
  function restore() {
    setChart(name, categories, data);
    drillupBtn.destroy();
  }
```

Then I added button handling in the `point.events.click`:

```
          click: function() {
            var drilldown = this.drilldown,
              chart = this.series.chart;
            if (drilldown) { // drill down
              setChart(drilldown.name, drilldown.categories, drilldown.data, drilldown.color);
              drillupBtn = chart.renderer.button("Drill up", 100, 100, function() {
                restore();
              }).add();
            } else { // restore
              restore();
            }
          }
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/md416hec/

---

**API reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#button